# How to setup a template with custom bullets and styles in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2007

I have created a document with a cover page, and back page, and would like to have staff where I work use it as a default document template. However, I have used custom bullet points, and have customised the style of the document so that it matches our corporate style.

**How do I save the bullet points so that the document uses the bullet points in the order I specify?**

I want the document to have default bullet points that I have created, however when I open the document and press the bullet point button, it uses standard Word bullets. I can select the bullets manually by selecting 'Document bullets' from the dropdown, but the user will have no way of telling which should be bullet1, bullet2 etc...

**I also need to know how to remove bullet points that I have been testing from the 'Document bullets' list!**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but to remove bullets you don't want to appear in the gallery, click the drop down to see the gallery, right click a bullet you no longer need there, and choose Remove.

(I know this is only half of the original question, but you seem to have the multi-level bit sorted now)

Comment: The problem is that in the 'document library' section, I don't have a remove option from the right click menu - I only have:

add library
add gallery to quick access toolbar

Comment: I can't see the options you are talking about for a 'document library'. 
What I am looking at is the drop down of bullet styles from the bullets button in the Paragraph group on the Home ribbon, (or numbering, or multilevel lists), then I right click on a bullet I don't want and choose > Remove. Which part of that does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this article, "Creating Microsoft Office Word 2007 Templates" from Microsoft, http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/HA102373631033.aspx.

Comment: thanks - I've managed to create the template ok, it's just the bullet points I need help with really, and there is no mention of them in that article

Comment: Ah, sorry, mis-understood your question.    I'll have to play with Word 2007 to figure it out, but won't have a chance to do that until Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered 1 part of my question - you have to click the small icon next to the normal bullet list called 'multi level list' and change your styles in there.

I still don't know how to remove certain bullets from the document bullets section though!